# OSX: EPSON printer fails when controlled by CUPS

Tags: mac-osx, printing, cups

I have an application that I developed that controls access to the printer for specific users.  I accomplish this using CUPS and the lpadmin commands

```
lpadmin -u allow:"+PRINT_USER_NAME+" -p "+printerName
lpadmin -u deny:"+PRINT_USER_NAME+" -p "+printerName
```

This command seems to work great for all but this EPSON Stylus Pro 9800 printer.  Even if the user is allowed to print, this error message appears in the queue

```
/Library/Printers/EPSON/InkjetPrinter2/Filter/rastertoescpII.app/Contents/MacOS/rastertoescpII failed
```

Now here is the kicker, that I believe is the key.  When a user is allowed to print, then show up in the CUPS control panel as being allowed like this

[image]

But if I remove that user from the Allow and Prevent list completely, essentially saying that are allowed to print then everything works great.  So the error message only appears if the user is on the CUPS controlled Allowed list.

So I can think of 2 options:

1) Figure out why using CUPS for access control causes this issue with this specific printer.

2) Figure out how (using the command line) to take a user Off of the Deny list without using the `lpadmin -u allow` command.  This should make it that user is no longer on any CUPS access control list at all, which has proven to work.

Option #2 seems like the easiest option.  Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, when with option too and used the command

`lpadmin -u allow:all -p "+printerName`

This essentially clears out the CUPS access control list on both approve and deny side, thus giving me the result I want that works.  Though I am curious on why this is happening in the first place.